# What happens when MLCC breaks due to over voltage?

Tags: capacitor

I am curious about what will happen to the characteristics of the capacitor when 220VAC is applied to 50V rated capacitor?

Will it short or open?

Comment: Do you mean "light emitting" characteristics, or smoke-emitting? Or explosive equivalent? - Just kidding...

Comment: *Will it short or open?* That depends on the type of capacitor. It might short (or have a low resistance) first and then explode resulting in an open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mains voltage can push very high current into the failing MLCC insulation layers. The rate of heat build up will be very high and that cause almost sudden material expansion causing explosive disintegration of the whole unit.

Expect to see this in milliseconds.